# get the Bitmap from ImageView in a ListView

Tags: android

I have a `ListActivity` that displays two pieces of information in each line of the list (one image sett in an `ImageView` and a text description set in a `TextView`). These information I get through a XML file from a download. Every thing works fine!!!!! :-).

On `OnListItemClick`, I would like to get the `Bitmap` from the `ImageView` that the user selected.

To get an image from an `ImageView`, I use this :

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) l.findViewById(R.id.imageViewXYZ);
img.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = img.getDrawingCache();
```

But inside the `onClick` event of the `ListActivity`, how can I get the this bitmap?

Answer (score 3):

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewXYZ);
            final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            final Bitmap yourBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    });
```

Code assumes, that you have a bitmap set in ListViews ImageView item through `setImageBitmap` (cast to BitmapDrawable)

Comment: As you told, but it´s not working, it´s giving a NullPointExecption... the "img" can not get in the ListView the ImageView... final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();


Is there another way to get the Bitmap from the ListView? I´m using an ListActivity inflate in the TabActivity as you see in the image above.

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Does your list items have ImageViews? When you click on an item you get item view in your onItemClick method and ImageView must be somewhere the in the hierarchy